# How to map an array of Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, mapping

I am stuck with mapping in array of objects.
Please find the below code

```
const array = [
  {
    user: "User1",
    cities: ["city1", "city2", "city3"],
  },
  {
    user: "User2",
    cities: ["city2", "city3", "city4"],
  },
];

let x = {};

array.map((item) => {
  let user = item.user;
  let cities = item.cities;
  cities.map((city) => (x[city] = user));
});
```

Now it returns like this:

```
const resArray = [{ city1: "User1", city2: "User2", city3: "User2", city4: "User2" }]
```

I want the array like this:

```
const resArray = [
  { city1: ["User1"] },
  { city2: ["User1", "User2"] },
  { city3: ["User1", "User2"] },
  { city4: ["User2"] },
];
```

Can anyone please help me out.

**Thanks**

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach` or an actual loop. In this case it seems loops are the easiest way forward, as you need to iterate and group at the same time.

Comment: Side note: *"I want the array like this"* That seems like a very awkward structure to make use of. Why not a single object with `city1` and such as properties?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @VLAZ and @ T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let x = {};
array.forEach((item) => {
  item.cities.forEach((city) => {
    x[city] = item.cities.includes(city) ? [...x[city] ? x[city] : [], item.user] : [];
  });
});
```

Comment: Please check either my response or the response below from sabbir.alam as an actual answer.To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have been assigning user to city each time. Instead the x[city] should be an array and you should push the new user inside that array.

Try this,

```
const array = [
  {
    user: "User1",
    cities: ["city1", "city2", "city3"],
  },
  {
    user: "User2",
    cities: ["city2", "city3", "city4"],
  },
];

let x = {};

array.map((item) => {
  let user = item.user;
  let cities = item.cities;
  cities.map((city) => {
    if(x[city] && x[city].length) {
      x[city].push(user);
    } else{
      x[city] = [user];
    }
  });
});

const res = Object.keys(x).map(key => { return {[key]: x[key]}});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please dont' forget to check solved if this answer solves your problem.

Comment: I already checked with all the solutions, all are working fine. 
Thanks again